# Use billing_company from woocommerce field as username

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a user registration form from woocommerce where users can register to create a account. Right now the username generated is first name. Is it possible to use the billing_company field as the username upon a woocommerce registration instead of the first name?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom function hooked into woocommerce_new_customer_data filter hook. This code will combine first name and last name as a username. Better than using the billing company

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'custom_new_customer_data', 10, 1 );
function custom_new_customer_data( $cust_customer_data ){

    // get the first and last billing names
    if(isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])) $first_name = $_POST['billing_first_name'];
    if(isset($_POST['billing_last_name'])) $last_name = $_POST['billing_last_name'];


    // the customer billing complete name
    if( ! empty($first_name) || ! empty($last_name) ) {
        $user_name = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
    }

    // Replacing 'user_login' in the user data array, before data is inserted
    if( ! empty($user_name ) ) {
        $cust_customer_data['user_login'] = sanitize_user( str_replace( ' ', '_', $user_name ) );
    }
    return $cust_customer_data; 
}
```